# How to upload image for non rest api through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My application is a web socket connection and i am using TCP sampler for other data but for image uploading what is procedure to use in Jmeter. Could you please let me how to handle image upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler in order to send file over TCP socket connection.

1. Install HTTP Raw Request Sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager HTTP Raw Request]
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   directFileSender=1
   ```
3. Get example file upload request from [testSendFile.raw](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/httpraw/src/test/resources/testSendFile.raw) and amend it according to your requirements
4. Save the file from point 3 somewhere in your file system
5. Set `Request Data` of the HTTP Raw Request plugin to point to the file from point 4.

More information:

- [fileupload test with JMeter](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html)
- [HTTP Raw Request for SOAP + MTOM](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/VDqXDNDCr6w)

Comment: Its not working for me. I have a image and i am doing for post ad api. In that there is an body data {
  "cmd" : "",
  "sid" : "${sid}",
  "data" : {
        "ads_image" : "\/9j\/4AAMIdwGCi9B9c4r\r\nzEa7ozFJPsLI0WMFH6\/XIOa7bTtQtLq3k",
  }
}
for this ads_image we are encrypting and sending the image.. for this i need to do... i am getting this error org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 0